# Coefficients of a power series, an algebraic identity

Tags: power-series, theta-functions

Given the following 4 functions:
\begin{align}
\theta_1(0, \tau) &= 2(q^{1/4} + q^{9/4} + q^{25/4} + \ddots), \\
\theta_2(0, \tau) &= 1-2q+2q^4-2q^9+ \ddots), \\
\theta_3(0, \tau) &= 1+2q+2q^4+2q^9+ \ddots), \\
\theta_4(0, \tau) &= 2\pi(q^{1/4} -3q^{9/4} + 5q^{25/4} - \ddots). 
\end{align}

Prove that:

$\theta_4(0, \tau) = \pi \bigl(\theta_1(0, \tau) \cdot \theta_2(0, \tau) \cdot\theta_3(0, \tau) \bigr)$

I think it can solved both by calculations or by using some special properties of the theta functions. In this case, note that $\theta_4$ is the derivative of the $\theta$ function as defined in Chandrasekharan's "Elliptic Functions". I would prefer the first method.

Comment: That's Jacobi's *aequatio identica satis abstrusa*. You might need the triple product identity and [something like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700542). Not writing an answer myself because I suspect that you can now provide an answer yourself.